# Youtube API v3: Retrieving multiple channels at once (quota, limits)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The "channels.list" function has a "id" parameter ("The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube channel ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved")

My tests showed that it's possible to retrieve 50 channels at once. Otherwise I'm getting a (400) Bad Request in Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse.
Is this because of the maximum length of HTTP GET requests, or is this a server side limit?

And is it better for the quota consumption to make one call with multiple channel ids or is it the same as multiple requests with one channel id each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should be an API limit.

This is definitely better to batch your requests with commas. as it'll only count as 1 request as far as quotas are concerned.